# Error opening android support appcompat in eclipse from dandar3

Tags: android, eclipse, google-play-services

dandar3 Google Play Services for eclipse always worked well. All project has a good synchronization.

But last time I caught bug of synchronization in android support appcompat project. Here is it:

[image: ResultReceiver.aidl]

[image]

All libraries in android support appcompat is correct. My system is Linux Mint 64. My default java is java-8-oracle(I tryed java-8-openjdk-amd64 no effect).

Mayby somebody faced that error? Please do not offer Android Studio. Thank you.

Comment: Did you try opening a Github issue? Even if you don't want to use Android Studio, you should really be using Gradle instead of downloading these libraries

Comment: No, I did not try.. I using two facets in my eclipse project. First for synchronization code, second for build whith gradle. Build whith gradle is ok. But code synchronization  is bad, because error in libs of project.

Comment: You can compile all these support libraries using Gradle. Are you doing that?

Comment: Yes build whith gradle is ok. Gradle scripts is good.

Comment: Not sure if you're talking about literally `compile "com.android.support:support...:26.0.1"` or not

Comment: I am talking exactly about that. My gradle script very well. But my code parsing from old eclipse android plugin. I have two facets in eclipse project.

Comment: I don't know what facets are, sorry. I haven't used Eclipse heavily in years. I only think that this library is busted, and I'm confused why you need to download the sources and set them up in eclipse at all

Comment: https://github.com/dandar3 is actualizating this library every version. And in eclipse it worked well.

Comment: Alright, well, you may have better  luck contacting the developer directly. https://github.com/dandar3/android-support-compat/issues

Comment: Thanks i will try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More details on the ticket on GitHub ([link](https://github.com/dandar3/android-support-compat/issues/1)) but just to summarise it appears to be due to the fact that `aidl` tool only supports interfaces, it logs the message as an error and by design Google ADT plugin shows external errors as compiler errors.

The issue affects the Android Support Libraries 26.0.0 for Eclipse listed below, from which I will remove the offending `.aidl` files and release them again.

- android-support-compat
- android-support-media-compat
- android-support-v4

---

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/tools/aidl/+/master/aidl.cpp#580

```
547 AidlError load_and_validate_aidl(
...
575  AidlDocument* parsed_doc = p.GetDocument();
576
577  unique_ptr<AidlInterface> interface(parsed_doc->ReleaseInterface());
578
579  if (!interface) {
580    LOG(ERROR) << "refusing to generate code from aidl file defining "
581                  "parcelable";
582    return AidlError::FOUND_PARCELABLE;
583  }
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. Ticket on GitHub is very useful.